# How to get matrix positions surrounded by common data?

Tags: java, matrix

I have a defined matrix in Java

```
int[][] a={
    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {0,1,0,1,0,1},
    {0,0,1,0,1,0}
};
```

So I want to know what positions on matrix are surrounded by the lines made of "1" values, i.e., the group of positions with value of "0", as if the "1" were the perimeter of a irregular figure, and "0" values within the perimeter its area (in this case: a[2][3], a[3][1], a[3][2], a[3][3], a[3][4], a[4][2] and a[4][4]).

How can I get these positions automatically?

Comment: what is surrounded for you? as i understand surrounded, none of the examples you gave are right. in fact, no position is surrounded by "1"

Comment: how a[3][2] is sorrounded by "1"??

Comment: Look up the flood fill algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Thanks it looks that will help me to resolve my problem, I'll to comprobe it tonight, I didn't thought that the perimeter would be filled with a flood behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do what you want is to use [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), with no filling across diagonals. This will not help you by itself, but you can fill all regions that are connected to the edges of your array with some non-zero value. The remaining zeros in the array will be the elements that you crave.

Here is a simple implementation of flood fill:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.awt.Point;  // This is probably superfluous, an int[] with two elements would do fine here too

public class Test
{
    private static int[][] a = new int[][] {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 1 ,0, 1, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}
    };

    /*
     * Applies flood fills all elements accessible from array[row][col] with
     * value. If the element at (row, col) is already value, this method does
     * nothing.
     */
    private static void floodFill(int[][] array, int row, int col, int value)
    {
        int oldValue = array[row][col];
        if(oldValue == value)
            return;
        ArrayDeque<Point> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        queue.add(new Point(col, row));
        while(queue.size() > 0) {
            // Technically, removeLast would be more efficient, especially
            // since the order does not matter, but this is just an example
            Point point = queue.pop();
            int r = point.y;
            int c = point.x;
            array[r][c] = value;

            if(r > 0 && array[r - 1].length > c && array[r - 1][c] == oldValue)
                queue.add(new Point(c, r - 1));
            if(r < array.length - 1 && array[r + 1].length > c && array[r + 1][c] == oldValue)
                queue.add(new Point(c, r + 1));
            if(c > 0 && array[r][c - 1] == oldValue)
                queue.add(new Point(c - 1, r));
            if(c < array[r].length - 1 && array[r][c + 1] == oldValue)
                queue.add(new Point(c + 1, r));
        }
    }

    /*
     * Walks around the edges of the array and floods everthing connected to
     * them with ones. This relies on floodFill exiting early for areas that
     * were already filled.
     */
    private static void fillEdges(int[][] array)
    {
        // top row
        for(int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++)
            floodFill(array, 0, col, 1);
        // left column
        for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
            floodFill(array, row, 0, 1);
        // bottom row
        for(int col = 0; col < array[array.length - 1].length; col++)
            floodFill(array, array.length - 1, col, 1);
        // all trailing row segments (allows for ragged arrays)
        for(int row = 1; row < array.length - 1; row++) {
            int lengthToFill = array[row].length - Math.min(array[row - 1].length, array[row + 1].length);
            lengthToFill = (lengthToFill < 0) ? 1 : lengthToFill + 1;
            for(int col = array[row].length - lengthToFill; col < array[row].length; col++)
                floodFill(array, row, col, 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        fillEdges(a);
        for(int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
                if(a[row][col] == 0)
                    System.out.println("[" + row + "][" + col + "]");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This particular implementation is nice because it will work for arrays of arbitrary size and shape. I added a bit to check if a point is on the edge of a ragged array as well (comparing the lengths of the rows).

The output is exactly what you expect:

```
[2][3]
[3][1]
[3][2]
[3][3]
[3][4]
[4][2]
[4][4]
```

Comment: thanks it works!, it really helped me to understand how flood fill algorithm works

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple algorithm that uses helper functions to compute the indexes of the predecessor and successor of each element.

```
public class Test {

    public static final int N = 6;

    public static int isucc(int i, int j) {
        return (i * N + j + 1) / N;
    }

    public static int jsucc(int i, int j) {
        return (i * N + j + 1) % N;
    }

    public static int ipred(int i, int j) {
        return (i * N + j - 1) / N;
    }

    public static int jpred(int i, int j) {
        return (i * N + j - 1) % N;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] a={
                {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,1,0,0},
                {0,1,1,0,1,0},
                {1,0,0,0,0,1},
                {0,1,0,1,0,1},
                {0,0,1,0,1,0}
            };



        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {        
                if (i * N + j > 0 && i * N + j < N * N - 1 
                            && a[ipred(i,j)][jpred(i,j)] == 1 
                            && a[isucc(i,j)][jsucc(i,j)] == 1) {
                    System.out.println(i +  "," + j);
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

It prints:

```
2,3
2,5
4,0
4,2
4,4
5,3
```

Note that it can easily be extended to non-square matrices.

Dominique Ubersfeld

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I actually tryng to get 
a[2][3], a[3][1], a[3][2], a[3][3], a[3][4], a[4][2] and a[4][4]
like if "1" were the perimeter of a irregular figure and 0 inside them the area.