# changing all adjacent elements in a two dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to solve a problem that has to do with manipulating the elements of a 2D char vector . Imagine the vector as an X by Y matrix where X is the number of columns and Y is the number of rows. Initially all the elements are 0.

I need to write code that will, when I address an element of the vector by it's index (i.e vect[3][4]) and change it's value , change all elements adjacent to it in the matrix (4 elements - above, below, left, right) to the same value and then proceed to change all elements adjacent to those in the same fashion - but only as long as they have the same initial value as the first element addressed. Let's say the matrix is 9x5.

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> vect;
int x,y;
char input;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::vector<char> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        temp.push_back('0');
    }
    vect.push_back(temp);
} //used to initialize the vector of char vectors and set all the elements to 0
std::cin>>x;
std::cin>>y;
std::cin>>input;
table[y][x] = input; // changes the initial element to the value specified

/*imagine this as a matrix that already had some elements changed beforehand (at some point between the initialization and the code I need to write)
000000A00
000000AAA
000000A00
0A00000AA
0000AAAA0 */
```

Now if I enter let's say 2 for x, 3 for y and the letter B as char input, first the element vect[3][2] should change to B, then all those adjacent to it and so on until elements have changed to B, except those that weren't 0 even before the input was given or weren't adjacent to any 0 elements that have changed value as result of the input. So the matrix should look like this:

```
/*matrix after x=2, y=3, input=B
BBBBBBA00
BBBBBBAAA
BBBBBBA00
BABBBBBAA
BBBBAAAA0
*/
```

There's more to what the program is intended to be and I've figured out about 90% of it but I just can't wrap my head around this. Any ideas?

Comment: You are looking for the flood fill algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill?

Comment: Also, you only posted the initialization code here. SO is not a free coding service. If you wrote 90% of the code, post it here and let us know where the *specific* problem is.

Comment: alright. well, the rest of the code doesn't have anything to do with this particular problem. I didn't say I solved 90% of the problem I posted, just 90% of the whole program. And as you can see, the post is pretty expansive and possibly confusing as it is, didn't think it would make sense to post the code unrelated to this particular part of it.

Comment: and thx for the link, gonna look into it. It's not that I want someone to code for me lol, it's just that I'm learning programming on my own using only the internet , and some times you just come across a problem you have absolutely no reference to

Comment: I understand that. While I will not write the code for you, check out this post I made about flood fill in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42583801/2988730. It is not 100% related to what you are doing, but it might help you visualize a solution in C++, especially since the syntax should be similar enough to understand easily.

Comment: Here's another thing that might help: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flood-fill-algorithm-implement-fill-paint/

Comment: Great, thx a lot for the help, gonna check them all out :)